# Qual a diferença entre o Media Query Pointer e Any-Pointer?

Tags: html5, css3, media-queries

Estava vendo uma forma de determinar se o acesso do usuário é feito por um Desktop, normalmente tendo um *mouse* como dispositivo de interação. Ou se o usuário está acessando por um dispositivo Mobile, normalmente sem o *mouse* para fazer a interação com a tela.

Aí vi que existe a possibilidade de tratar isso com as regras `@media (pointer: X)` ou `@media (any-pointer: X)` onde em `pointer: X` você define se existe ou não um *mouse*.

`X` pode ser:

- `none`: Nenhum dispositivo apontador está disponível.
- `coarse`: Pelo menos um mecanismo de entrada inclui um dispositivo apontador de precisão limitada.
- `fine`: Pelo menos um mecanismo de entrada inclui um dispositivo apontador preciso.

**Dúvidas**

A dúvida é que tanto para `pointer` quanto `any-pointer` os valores são iguais e representam a mesma coisa, então qual é a diferença entre um e outro?

Existe alguma forma de reconhecer, **por CSS**, se o acesso está sendo por um dispositivo `mobile` *(que não tenha um mouse como dispositivo de entrada)* e aplicar uma folha de estilo específica?

Comment: O `pointer`leva em consideração o mecanismo de entrada principal.
o `any-pointer` não.
Vacê pode ler sobre eles nos links abaixo: [pointer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/pointer) [any-pointer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/any-pointer) Acredito que seja isso, espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score 1):

A diferença entre um e outro é que o [pointer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/pointer) irá testar apenas o dispositivo apontador primário (*primary pointing device*), enquanto o [any-pointer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/any-pointer) irá testar qualquer um que tiver disponível e entrar na *media query* apropriada (`fine` ou `coarse`).

> No caso do valor `none`, tanto faz usar `pointer` ou `any-pointer`, já
>   que ambos irão assumir `none` se não houver um dispositivo apontador.

Para exemplificar, vamos imaginar algumas situações:

> O termo *coars*e quer dizer no sentido de ruim, de qualidade inferior. Neste caso, seria de *baixa precisão*.

**Apontador principal:** *touch*

- `pointer: coarse`
- `any-pointer: coarse`

---

**Apontador principal:** *touch*
**Apontador secundário:** *mouse*

- `pointer: coarse`
- `any-pointer: fine` (por causa do mouse)

---

**Apontador principal:** *mouse*
**Apontador secundário:** *touch*

- `pointer: fine`
- `any-pointer: fine`

---

**Apontador principal:** *touchpad*

- `pointer: fine`
- `any-pointer: fine`

---

**Apontador principal:** *mouse*
**Apontador secundário:** *touchpad*

- `pointer: fine`
- `any-pointer: fine`

---

**Apontador principal:** *touchpad*
**Apontador secundário:** *mouse*

- `pointer: fine`
- `any-pointer: fine`

Veja que tanto o *mouse* quanto o *touchpad* são considerados dispositivos apontadores de alta precisão. Já o *touch* é considerado `coarse` (de baixa precisão). Outros dispositivos como trackball e aqueles botões no meio do teclado em notebooks antigos que movem o cursor eu não sei dizer se são `fine` ou `coarse` porque não os tenho para testar, mas suponho que ambos sejam `fine` também por moverem o ponteiro na tela, como faz o mouse e o touchpad. Não creio que o CSS irá saber distinguir a diferença a nível de hardware.

Resumindo, é mais vantagem usar `any-pointer` porque ele irá buscar o melhor dispositivo apontador, idependemente se ele é o principal ou não. Mas hoje em dia, esse recurso serve apenas para verificar se o dispositivo usado é *touch* (e alterar propriedades de elementos para facilitar o uso) ou utiliza um cursor na tela.

> Em resumo, geralmente um dispositivo móvel irá entrar em `coarse`,
>   enquanto que um desktop irá entrar em `fine` (se houver um mouse instalado. Caso contrário irá entrar em `none`).

Comment: Valeu Sam. E sobre determinar estilos CSS só para o dispositivo mobile com base no tipo de dispositivo de entrada se eh fine, none, etc. Sabe me dizer se eh possível?

Comment: No mobile sempre será `coarse` por causa do touch. A não ser que o cara use algum tipo de app que coloque um ponteiro na tela. Mas tb não sei se mesmo com o ponteiro na tela irá cair no `fine`. Tem um navegador mobile que emula um mouse. Vou testar com ele e te digo.

Comment: Era isso mesmo. No Puffin Web browser mobile cai no `fine` porque ele vem com um emulador de mouse nativo. Já no Chome mobile cai no `coarse`.

Comment: Então com essa técnica não da para definir se o acesso é mobile ou desktop, pois os dois são fine ou coarse?

Comment: Geralmente mobile é coarse (touch) e desktop fine (mouse). Só que se o cara acessar pelo Puffin, vai cair no fine porque ele tem um simulador de mouse embutido.

Comment: Sim valeu a dica