# Como aplicar um estilo CSS apenas para dispositivos que não possuem mouse?

Tags: html, css, cursor

Preciso ocultar um ícone "X" quando o dispositivo estiver em uma resolução web em que possua o cursor de ponteiro e manter nos dispositivos com touch (ex: tablet e mobile).

Não sei se preciso usar o [ponteiro de mídia](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/pointer), para remover o ícone nesse caso.

Testei este CSS, mais não consegui resolver:

```
 .menu-web__logo-icon-x {
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    min-width: 28px;
    min-height: 28px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: 16px;
   }
 }

 @media (cursor: pointer) {
   .menu-web {
     .menu-web__logo-icon-x {
       display: none;
      }
     }
   }
```

Como posso criar uma *media query* para determinar se o usuário possui (ou não) *mouse*?

Comment: Você considera o touchpad um mouse? Se tiver um mouse conectado no dispositivo touch, qual o comportamento esperado?

Comment: Não estou considerando o fato de o usuário utilizar um mouse no touchpad, não pensei nesse comportamento caso use um mouse por exemplo no tablet.

Comment: Isso pode te ajudar https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/351537/qual-a-diferen%c3%a7a-entre-o-media-query-pointer-e-any-pointer

Comment: Percebi que a media query ```pointer: fine```, não funciona em navegadores mais antigos como o IE8. Existe alguma outra possibilidade que funcione com esse navegador em especifico?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O *media feature* `pointer` permite que você faça uma *query* para determinar qual tipo de cursor o dispositivo do usuário possui.

De acordo com a [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/pointer), três valores de teste são possíveis:

| Valor de teste | Descrição |
| --- | --- |
| `none` | O mecanismo de *input* primário não inclui nenhum dispositivo para apontar. |
| `coarse` | O dispositivo de *input* primário inclui um dispositivo para apontar com **precisão limitada**. |
| `fine` | O dispositivo de *input* primário possui um dispositivo para apontar com boa precisão. |

Desse modo, a sua *media query* pode utilizar o valor de teste `none` para determinar se o usuário encontra-se em um dispositivo móvel sem nenhum equipamento para apontar (como um *mouse*).

Exemplo:

```css
/** Por padrão, assumiremos que o usuário possui um dispositivo para apontar. */
.no-pointing-device { display: none; }
.has-pointing-device { display: block; }

/** Media query para testar casos nos quais o usuário não tem dispositivo para apontar. */
@media (pointer: none) {
  .no-pointing-device { display: block; }
  .has-pointing-device { display: none; }
}
```

```html
<h1 class="no-pointing-device">Você não tem mouse conectado</h1>
<h1 class="has-pointing-device">Você tem mouse conectado</h1>
```

---

O código da pergunta não funcionou porque a *query* `cursor: pointer` não é válida. Repare que o teste `pointer` não existe na tabela acima.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, funcionou utilizando o valor ```pointer: fine```!